# ActiveJob: Accessible instance variables between callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I have the following snippet within my job:

```
before_enqueue do |job|
  # do something
  @car = create_car
end


before_perform do |job|
  # do something
  @car.update(type: 'broken')
end
```

but when the job is performed `@car` is a `nil`. Is it possible to pass somehow the instance variable from one callback to the second one? Even only `ID` would be fine. Cheers.

Comment: Is this a job class? Whats the job for?  The thing you're call the job on (guessing not a car) is typically passed into the job as shown here. http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html But if you've made a job class you could create an instance variable in the class that is used in the other methods/hooks (just move `@car` up a level in scope.

Comment: You can't have instance variables shared between enqueueing and performing as the pieces of codes can run on totally different servers. Anyway the whole thing you're trying to achieve seems a bit anti-activejob as you're doing stuff that should belong to a job process method in callback. You shouldn't do expensive and subject to errors things in callbacks as it will be extremely hard to traceback

Comment: It is useful when you want to implement chain of jobs that should follow one by one, e.g. for developing own data pipelines

Answer (score 2):

You would need to make this an instance variable off of `job` and access that way:

```
class Car < ActiveJob::Base
  attr_accessor :car
end
```

then

```
before_enqueue do |job|
  # do something
  job.car = create_car
end

before_perform do |job|
  # do something
  job.car.update(type: 'broken')
end
```

Comment: Did this actually work? Can't seem to get this to work (in Sidekiq)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what you're trying to do, I wanted to know which user enqueued a job without passing the user id to each job in perform. It doesn't look like ActiveJob lets you serialize new instance variables, so I just made use of the arguments variable:

```
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  before_enqueue do |job|
    # Get user_id from somewhere first
    job.arguments = [user_id, *job.arguments]
  end

  around_perform do |job, block|
    user_id = job.arguments.shift
    # Store user_id somewhere
    block.call
    # Ensure user_id is no longer stored
    # (why I'm using around_perform instead of before_perform)
  end
end
```

However, that causes problems if you use `perform_now` and not just `perform_later`, since any job performed "now" does not pass through `before_enqueue`. So here's an improved approach to allow `perform_now`:

```
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  before_enqueue do |job|
    job.arguments = ['_LATER_', user_id, *job.arguments]
  end

  around_perform do |job, block|
    if job.arguments[0] == '_LATER_'
      _, user_id = job.arguments.shift(2)
      store_somewhere(user_id) { block.call }
    else
      block.call
    end
  end
end
```